# How to swap submenu in different pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a submenu for the pages of my website. Each page will have a different submenu in the header. For example:

Inicio: menu 1
Sala de Investigación: menu2
Estudios Bíblicos: menu3

how can I do this using the if statement
Im creating my website using wordpress. My old web page is:justiciadedios.com

Answer (score 1):

Very easy.

Use Wordpress 3.0

Use the "Custom Menu" plugin to create different custom menus, one menu for each page.

Go to Appearance > Widgets and place several Custom Menu widgets wherever you want the menu, one widget for each Custom menu.

Download and install the Widget Logic Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Read the Widget logic instructions and use the PHP shortcodes to select which page each wiget will appear on. Have fun!